# How to make a matrix of 0 and 1?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I have a file containing some lines. Each line contains a Persian sentence, a tab and then an English word, which shows each sentence's class. I have to extract the 1000 most frequent words from this file and then I want to make a matrix. The columns of this matrix are the classes of the file (some files have 2 classes, some 3 and some, more) and the rows are these 1000 words (as like as the picture below (it's a small sample with English words but mine are Persian. d1 to d5 are classes)). I have to check each 1000 words in each class, if it exist there, add 1 to matrix (in its own place), and if not, add 0. How can I make such a matrix?

```
def makeMatrix(file):
    with open (file, encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
        for line in f1:
            line = line.strip().split("\t")
            lin = line[0].split()
            for word in lin:
             ????????????
```

sample matrix:

[image]

sample file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fx33cac3qemizmj/train1.txt?dl=0
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a matrix? It would be easier to make a `dict`, with the words as keys, and each item containing a list of classes that the word belongs to.

Comment: Take a look at [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different data structure would probably be a better match, at least initially.

I propose to use a `dict`, with words as the keys, and a set of classes as the value.

Note that I cannot read Persian, so I have no idea what the words mean, and there may be left-right issues when copying the results from IPython into this answer. My apologies in advance.

First, we read the file.

```
In [1]: with open('train1.txt', encoding = "utf-8") as f1:
   ...:     lines = f1.readlines()
   ...:
```

Import some types that we need, create the data-dict, and a frequency counter.

```
In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: data = defaultdict(set)

In [5]: freq = Counter()
```

Split each line into a sentence and a classification.
Next, split each lines into words. Add the word's classification to the data, and the word to the counter.

```
In [6]: for ln in lines:
   ...:     sentence, classification = ln.strip().split('\t')
   ...:     for word in sentence.split():
   ...:         data[word].add(classification)
   ...:         freq.update([word])
   ...:
```

Let's see what (for example) the five most common words are.

```
In [7]: freq.most_common(5)
Out[7]: [('پر', 53), ('اوقات', 3), ('فراغت', 3), ('زمین', 3), ('لطافت', 2)]
```

(There is a LTR/RTL issue here, it looks very different in IPython.)

Now look into the data to see which classes they belong to.

```
In [8]: for word in [t[0] for t in freq.most_common(5)]:
   ...:     print(word, data[word])
   ...:     
پر {'full', 'fill'}
اوقات {'fill'}
فراغت {'fill'}
زمین {'full', 'fill'}
لطافت {'full'}
```

With this approach, you can easily check if a word is in the data:

```
In [9]: 'اوقات' in data
Out[9]: True
```

And you can easily check which classes it belongs to:

```
In [10]: data['اوقات']
Out[10]: {'fill'}
```

**Edit:**

Now to turn this into a matrix. I'll show you the way to do this without and with `numpy`.

First, without `numpy`. A matrix can be represented as a nested list. I'm using a smaller (10x5) matrix instead of 1000x5 because the train1 dataset isn't that big. The initial matrix is filled with zeros, and the appropriate items will be set to 1 later.

```
In [11]: m = [[0,0,0,0,0] for j in range(10)]
```

Note: Do not use `[[0,0,0,0]]*10`, because that would generate a *shallow copy* of the inner list!

For the first index, we're going to use the ten most occuring words:

```
In [12]: J = [p[0] for p in freq.most_common(10)]
```

For the second index, we use the categories:

```
In [14]: K = ['fill', 'full', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Now to set the items.

```
In [16]: for j, word in enumerate(J):
    ...:     for cat in data[word]:
    ...:         m[j][K.index(cat)] = 1
    ...:
```

The resulting matrix:

```
In [17]: m
Out[17]: 
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

For numpy, it it mostly the same:

```
In [18]: import numpy as np

In [21]: m2 = np.zeros((10,5), dtype=np.uint8)

In [22]: for j, word in enumerate(J):
    ...:     for cat in data[word]:
    ...:         m2[j, K.index(cat)] = 1
    ...: 

In [23]: m2
Out[23]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need exactly a matrix because then I have to give this matrix to SVD. Actually, this is a part of LSA (latent semantic analysis) algorithm.

Comment: What is SVD in this context, and what form should the matrix have? A numpy array, or a nested list?

Comment: @sara The In and Out come from [IPython](https://ipython.org/), a very useful interactive python environment. Just copy the text *after* the "In[]" and make sure you keep the correct indentation.

Comment: @ Roland Smith, it works correctly. Now I have to give that to SVD and after that I have to make a vector for each word separately according to this matrix, but how can I define, which number is for which word in the matrix? thanks

Comment: @sara The index for the words in the `J` list is the same as the row index in the matrix...

Comment: @ Roland Smith, I know, but because then I have to compare a test data with this train data I have to assign them to their strings (words) as like as the pictures that I added above, so that I can continue the code saying that for example ,if I have 2 words in the test set, if any word in the query (the test sentence) is in train set, add the vectors of them together. How can I assign them to words? (I wrote word1 = (J[0] == U[0,:]) but it returns "false". (after applying SVD, there is U, s, Vt)

Comment: @sara Sorry, but I don't understand.